# May the training set and validation set overlap?

Tags: machine-learning, training, data-science-model

May the training set and validation set overlap?

Similarly, may the testing set and validation set overlap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Definitions, so we are on the same page:

- **Training set**: the data points used to train the model.
- **Validation set:** the data points to keep checking the performance of your model in order to know when to stop training.
- **Testing set**: the data points used to check the performance once training is finished.

---

## May training and validation sets overlap?

They **should not**.

The validation set is used to know when to stop training your model. The idea is that you check your model performance often and when there seems to be no more improvement, you stop.

Take a look at the plot below. It is plotting the *loss* of the model. If the *loss* is still decreasing means that you can keep on improving your model, but if the *loss* stops decreasing you stop training.

Notice how the *valid* *loss* stops decreasing before the *train* *loss*. That is because the model could keep improving to improve the performance on the *training set*, but if you do that, you will get **overfitting**. So, by having an unseen *validation set*, you will stop training earlier and not **overfit** your mode, otherwise, if you keep on training, the **accuracy** on the *validation set* will start to **decrease**.

That means that if the two sets **overlap**, the *validation loss* will become more similar to the *training loss*, so you model will keep on training and you will overfit your model.

[image]

---

## May validation and testing sets overlap?

They **should not**.

You already used your *validation set* to stop training your model. That means that you already know the performance of your model again the *validation set*.

Now your model is trained and you want to test your model with unseen data points, i.e. with the *testing set*. If your sets overlap, you are **biasing** your test results towards the performance which you **already know** your model has.

Comment: This really helps me.

Comment: Happy to hear :)

Comment: @BrunoGL How about for the case of cross-validation? If I understand correctly, the training data and validation data overlap during the rotation. Is that considered ok? Thanks.

Comment: @yoystein yes that is ok, and you want that as well. One strategy you can have is: use *training* and *validation* set during cross-validation and hyper-parameter optimization. Then, once you figure out your best hyper-parameters and stoping critirea, retrain and use the *test* set for final testing.